# 3D Convex Hull's Volume

Tags: c++, math, 3d, convex-hull

I have the points of a 3D convex hull, I want to find out the volume of the convex hull. Anyone knows any methods to do so? It would be really nice to inform me about any C++ library that can do that for me.

Comment: If I were you, I'd post two questions if I had two questions.

Comment: I cannot do that because I can ask one question in every 90 mins.

Comment: Are you in such a hurry that you need both answers within 90 minutes? Are you sure you will have received an answer, digested it and implemented the first answer and moved on to the second answer within 90 minutes?

Comment: yeah, you are right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the volume, simply see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron#Volume), under "Orientable polyhedra". You want the formula with `volume = 1/3 * sum...`

Answer (score 1):

If your input is just a set of points, you will need the faces of the convex hull to apply the formula bellow.
This is implemented in [CGAL](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Convex_hull_3/) or qhull. Once, the convex hull is computed, you just have to enumerate all facets (this is easy in CGAL) and add their volume.